# How to override some VIM system settings?

Tags: vim

New Linux distros come with some quite sensible system `vim` settings that are mostly ok to use, but I would still like to override some of them.

For example the default Ubuntu and Raspbian vim config has mouse support on (`set mouse=a`) which I don't like. However as soon as I create `~/.vimrc` and put `set mouse=` in there, or any other setting for that matter, *I lose all* the system settings, like syntax highlighting, indentation, etc and `vim` comes up with very basic defaults.

How can I keep the systems settings while overriding just one or two of them?

---

Simple test case:

1. Start Debian in docker with `docker run --rm -it debian:latest`
2. Once started install VIM with: `apt update && apt -y install vim`
3. Test `vim /etc/passwd`:

   [image: vim with system settings]
4. `touch ~/.vimrc` - just creating the file is enough
5. Test `vim /etc/passwd` again:

   [image: vim with default settings]

In the first case the system settings like syntax highlighting and mouse support is configured, but as soon as I create (even empty) `~/.vimrc` then `vim` comes up with just the basic default settings.

It's a default Debian vim:

```
root@213ccd4660db:/# vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jun 15 2019 16:41:15)
Included patches: 1-875, 878, 884, 948, 1046, 1365-1368, 1382, 1401
```

Comment: My version is *7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Oct 13 2020 16:04:38), Included patches: 1-1689, Extra patches: 8.0.0056* (from the `:version` command). Settings in `/etc/vim/vimrc` are kept, even though I also have a `$HOME/.vimrc`.

Comment: If all else fails, you could explicitly include global settings with the `source` command in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: @berndbausch thanks, will experiment with `source`. For now added a simple testcase to my question.

Comment: @muru that's it indeed, thanks! Feel free to mark this as a duplicate or add the link as the answer and I will accept it. Thanks a lot!!